# Is there a way to have this update with browser resize rather than refresh alone?

Tags: jquery

As the title asks... Is there a way to have this update with browser resize rather than refresh alone?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#footer-container").css({'height':($("#footer").height()+'px')});
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-browser window resize event - JavaScript / jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599288/cross-browser-window-resize-event-javascript-jquery) or [JQuery: Detecting a Browser Resize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031872/jquery-detecting-a-browser-resize)

Comment: Also, if you search your _exact_ title in google this comes up: [Make an equal height function resizeable on window resize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903181/make-an-equal-height-function-resizeable-on-window-resize)

Comment: I don't understand why people even bother answering questions like this...

Comment: I did a search on here and nothing came up that made sense to me. Sorry for duplicate :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.resize()`

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   $("#footer-container").css({'height':($("#footer").height()+'px')});
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: This worked for me thank you. I want it to do the resize before window resize as well so I wrote it like this.

`$( document ).ready(function() {
 $("#footer-container").css({'height':($("#footer").height()+'px')});
 $(window).resize(function(){
   $("#footer-container").css({'height':($("#footer").height()+'px')});
 });
});`

Comment: You can just trigger resize like this - `$(window).resize(function(){
   $("#footer-container").css({'height':($("#footer").height()+'px')});
}).resize();`

Comment: Oh that's so much cleaner! I gotta say I'm not understanding how that is working though.

Comment: @Tom You can follow the api `--->` http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Ah I see, it applies it normally and when you append the ".resize();" to it, it also runs it for that action as well. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event handler to the window object for the resize event.

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {} );
```